# Signal handler (segv) unable to complete before device crashes

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, signals

I have installed a handler (say, crashHandler()) which has a bit of file output functionality. It is a linux thread which registers for SIGSEGV with the crashHandler(). File writing is requred, as it stores the stack trace to persistent storage.
   It works most of the times. But in a specific scenario, the function (crashHandler()) executes the function partly (I can see logs) and then device reboots. Can someone help me with a way to deal with such ?

Comment: Corollary : How to handle SIGSEGV such that the stack trace is preserved (persistent) for later debugging ? Please note that the core dump is not an option in this case, as there is very limited space.

Answer (score 1):

The first question to ask here is *why* the device rebooted. Normally having an ordinary application crash won't cause a kernel-level or hardware-level reboot. Most likely, you're either hitting a watchdog timer before the crash handler completes (in which case you should extend the watchdog timeout - do NOT reset the timer from within the crash handler though, as then you're risking problems in the crash handler itself preventing a reboot), or this is pid 1 and it's crashing within the SIGSEGV handler, causing a kernel panic due to pid 1 (init) dying.

If it's the latter, you need to be more careful with what you do in that crash handler. Remember, you just crashed. You *know* memory is corrupt, but you don't know *how* it's corrupt. It may be corrupt in ways that affect the crash handler itself - e.g. if you corrupt the heap metadata, you may be unable to allocate memory without crashing for real this time. You should keep what you do in that handler to a bare minimum - in particular, avoid calling any library functions that are not documented as being [async-signal-safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and avoid using any complex (pointer-containing) data structures or dynamically allocated memory. For the highest level of safety,  limit yourself to just fork() and exec()ing another process that will use debugger APIs (`ptrace()` and `/proc/$PID/mem`) to perform memory dumps or whatever else you might need.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for a detailed explanation of possibilities. What I gathered is, since the crashhandler() is getting  executed, it is likely that watchdog timer is kicking in. If so, how do I increase it ?  I also wanted to confirm that if the pid 1 death happens, I don't see any way crashhandler gets even a chance to be called. Is that correct?